# meaning of "pink" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> There were very few beauties, and such as there were were not very
> handsome. Miss Iremonger did not look well, and Mrs. Blount was the
> only one much admired. She appeared exactly as she did in September,
> with the same broad face, diamond bandeau, white shoes, **pink**
> husband, and fat neck.

This is from [Jane Austen's letter to her sister Cassandra](http://book.99csw.com/book/136/4400.htm).
I wonder what does "pink" mean in this context. Does it mean Mrs. Blount's husband has a pink face or is there any kind of metaphor to it?

Comment: Given that it's a letter to her sister, it's very likely that it's an inside joke. Perhaps the sister made some comment about the rosiness of his cheeks back in September.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mr Blount either has a fair complexion and rosy cheeks, or possibly his face is rather red. I don't think there is any metaphor involved.